# Ionic CLI error while adding plugin

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, android-sdk-tools

I am getting this error while adding any cordova / ionic plugin.Can any one Please help me.Thanks

```
ERROR:
connect ETIMEDOUT 50.17.177.14:80
at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:874:11)
at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:897:20)
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect asoncomplete
```

Comment: I think you have done something wrong during installation. Give this a try error https://evothings.com/doc/build/cordova-install-windows.html

Comment: @Jammy Could be a connection time out issue. Ensure that your firewall is not blocking plugin downloads.